# Entropy of a random vector: 3 coins

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I have a sample question for an exam and would like some help understanding if I'm approaching it correctly. The question:

```
We toss three fair (unbiased) coins. 
For each of them, heads and tails have the identical probability 1/2.
The resulting random value is a vector hx1, x2, x3i where xi ∈ {H, T}.
    1. Compute entropy of this random variable.
    2. How does the entropy change if one of the three coins is unfair (biased) and it always lands with heads up?
```

With a fair coin there are 8 possible outcomes/vectors: HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, TTT, TTH, THT, THH
Since the coins are fair, each is equally likely, so we have $H(X) = log_28 = 3$

Then if one coin is biased to heads, the outcomes are HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, TTH, THT, THH
and the calculation of the entropy changes to $H(X) = log_27 ≈ 2.81$, so the entropy decreases slightly.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: No, if one coin always comes up heads then there are only 4 possible outcomes and the entropy is 2 bits. Intuitively each fair coin provides 1 bit of entropy and the bad coin provides no entropy because it's deterministic.

Comment: @Karl but you don't know what is position of bad coin.

Comment: @mihalid We don't know the index of the bad coin, but (as I interpret the given wording) the bad coin still has a fixed index. Your interpretation (that the experiment includes randomizing the coin order) makes it more interesting, though.

Comment: I was not sure if the ordering matters, as it is represented as a random vector. I was working as if the order was irrelevant, i.e. 8 outcomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct, because outcomes (assuming the position of bad coin is chosen uniformly) do not have equal probability.

For example, outcome $HTT$ has probability $1/12$: it requires the first coin to be bad ($1/3$) and rolling tale twice ($1/4$). However, outcome $HHT$ has probability $2/12$ (it allows two positions for bad coin).

Overall, we have $3$ outcomes with probability $1/12$, $3$ outcomes with probability $2/12$ and one outcome ($HHH$) with probability $3/12$, for total entropy

$$-\frac{3}{12} \log_2 \frac{1}{12} -\frac{6}{12} \log_2 \frac{2}{12} - \frac{3}{12} \log_2 \frac{3}{12} \approx 2.69$$

Comment: I think I see your point. Either way the entropy decreases it seems, the degree is what differs.

Comment: Yes, uniform distribution has maximal entropy, so any deviation from it decreases the entropy.